# What is the Difference between <ion-list> and <div class=“list”> in Ionic framework?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I am learner and i would like to know what is the diff b/w ionic and HTML tags and which tags are good for Hybrid mobile developing apps,Can some one suggest me please below two code working fine in my mobile app but which tags are most preferable?

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item item-divider"> <!-- this creates the divider -->
  </div>
  <a class="item" href="#">
  </a>
```

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="item-toggle">
    Enable Friends
    <label class="toggle">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="settings.enableFriends">
      <div class="track">
        <div class="handle"></div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <ion-list> and <div class="list"> in Ionic framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120777/difference-between-ion-list-and-div-class-list-in-ionic-framework)

Answer (score 1):

> The difference between the two are the pure html that just use the
> css, or the directives that have extended the functionality.
>
> The ion- prefixed directives, ion-list,ion-item, etc, are angular
> directives that let you have extended features (swipe to delete,
> reorder, etc).
> [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-html-tags-when-use-ion-prefix-and-when-not/3933/2)

As mentioned here,  main difference is that ionic tags serves more functionalities, and other than that.

Comment: Is there any performance issue occurs if we use pure html tags inside <ionic-content>?

Comment: Of course no, you can think ionic tags like normal tag with class= "something", namely with css extras. Therefore, using pure tags or html tags does not differ at all in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks,But is there is no best ionic-tags documentation for UI beatification like below link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_images_side_by_side.asp

Comment: Ionic uses term "component" that together creates an app so documentations are based on that. Therefore, you search for proper component while developing. Ionic documentation is actually is best I think, it provides demos for its components. So, when you need specific functionality, find it in documentation and use the corresponding demo(or mostly documentation is enough). Here is the documentation if you have not seen yet: https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/

Answer (score 0):

ion-list comes with certain styles already applied to it so that you do not have to write custom CSS for them to look presentable. Also ion-list has features that come out of box enabling you to put together a quick prototype. It also includes features like swipe which are normal actions taken by users on mobile so that developers dont have to write custom javascript to enable such features.

Comment: Thanks @Sameeksha Kumari